# calculation of the integral method trapeze

Tags: fortran, openmp, integral

I have already current code, but it still not working. If code is correct, please help how I can compile it. I had tried it to compile so:

> gfortran trap.f -fopenmp

```
PROGRAM TRAP
USE OMP_LIB
DOUBLE PRECISION INTEG, TMPINT  
DOUBLE PRECISION A, B      
PARAMETER (A=3.0, B=7.0)  
INTEGER N      
PARAMETER (N=10)
DOUBLE PRECISION H         
DOUBLE PRECISION X
INTEGER I
DOUBLE PRECISION F         
H = (B-A)/N
INTEG = 0.0
TMPINT = 0.0
!$omp parallel firstprivate(X, TMPINT) shared(INTEG)
!$omp do
DO 10 I=1,N-1,1
X=A+I*H
TMPINT = TMPINT + F(X)
10   CONTINUE
!$omp end do
!$omp critical
INTEG = INTEG + TMPINT
!$omp end critical
!$omp end parallel 
NTEG = (INTEG+(F(A)+F(B))/2.0)*H
PRINT *, "WITH N=", N, "INTEGRAL=", INTEG
END
FUNCTION F(X)
DOUBLE PRECISION X
F = X / (X + 1) * EXP(-X + 2)
END
```

Compiler gives following problems:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPknv.png][1]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYkmN.png][2]

Comment: Why so many downvotes? (though it is better to include the error messages as text into the Question...)

Comment: Please give the error message in text form. Screen readers cannot translate images, and it is quite difficult to find the error message by full text searches...

Comment: [I see, it seems like the OP had posted similar questions many times (?). Hmm.]

Answer (score 1):

Your program has a suffix `.f`, so gfortran assumes that the code is in fixed format and complains that many statements are "unclassifiable". To fix this, change the file name to `trap.f90` and compile as `gfortran -fopenmp trap.f90` to assume free format. There are also other problems: one is that the return type of function `F(X)` does not match with the type declared in the main program, so `F(X)` needs to be modified as

```
FUNCTION F(X)
implicit none                     !<--- this is always recommended
DOUBLE PRECISION X, F             !<--- add F here
F = X / (X + 1) * EXP(-X + 2)
END
```

Another issue is that `NTEG` is probably a typo of `INTEG`, so it should be modified as

```
INTEG = (INTEG+(F(A)+F(B))/2.0)*H
```

(this is automatically detected if we have `implicit none` in the main program). Now running the code with, e.g. 8 threads, gives

```
$ OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./a.out
WITH N=          10 INTEGRAL=  0.28927708626319770
```

while the [exact result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20x%2F%28x%2B1%29*exp%28-x%2B2%29%20from%203%20to%207) is 0.28598... Increasing the value of `N`, we can confirm that the agreement becomes better:

```
WITH N=         100 INTEGRAL=  0.28602065571967972
WITH N=        1000 INTEGRAL=  0.28598803555916535
WITH N=       10000 INTEGRAL=  0.28598770935198736
WITH N=      100000 INTEGRAL=  0.28598770608991503
```

---

BTW, it is probably easier to use the reduction clause to do the same thing, for example:

```
INTEG = 0.0

!$omp parallel do reduction(+ : integ) private(x)                                   
DO I = 1, N-1                                                                       
    X = A + I * H
    INTEG = INTEG + F( X )
ENDDO
!$omp end parallel do                                                               

INTEG = (INTEG+(F(A)+F(B))/2.0)*H
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is in fixed form (`.f`). Therefore, you must code by the rules of the fixed format: The first six characters on each line have a special meaning and should be blank unless you specify a comment in the first position, a line continuation (sixth position), or statement labels `10`.

If you format your code accordingly, the compiler complains about a mismatch in the return value of `F(X)`. As you do not use `implicit none`, the type is defined by the first letter of the function, and `F` maps to a (single precision) real. So you need to specify the return type explicitly.

Then the code looks like:

```
      PROGRAM TRAP
      USE OMP_LIB
      DOUBLE PRECISION INTEG, TMPINT  
      DOUBLE PRECISION A, B      
      PARAMETER (A=3.0, B=7.0)  
      INTEGER N      
      PARAMETER (N=10)
      DOUBLE PRECISION H         
      DOUBLE PRECISION X
      INTEGER I
      DOUBLE PRECISION F         
      H = (B-A)/N
      INTEG = 0.0
      TMPINT = 0.0
c$omp parallel firstprivate(X, TMPINT) shared(INTEG)
c$omp do
      DO 10 I=1,N-1,1
      X=A+I*H
      TMPINT = TMPINT + F(X)
10    CONTINUE
c$omp end do
c$omp critical
      INTEG = INTEG + TMPINT
c$omp end critical
c$omp end parallel 
      INTEG = (INTEG+(F(A)+F(B))/2.0)*H
      PRINT *, "WITH N=", N, "INTEGRAL=", INTEG
      END

      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION F(X)
      DOUBLE PRECISION X
      F = X / (X + 1) * EXP(-X + 2)
      END
```

[Please note that I also fixed the `NTAG =` line into `INTEG=` as I believe this is intended. I did not check the code for validity. ]

Comment: @IanH Sorry, I confused that. In FORTRAN 77, only `c` and `*` [denote comments](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf-3.html#sh-3.2.1), but of course you can use later standards in fixed form as well. Corrected...

Comment: I tried to compile your code, and received the following:          FUNCTION F(X)
1
Error: Unclassifiable statement at (1)
ttrap.f90:1.12:

PROGRAM TRAP
            1
ttrap.f90:13.18:

INTEGER I         
                  2
Error: Two main PROGRAMs at (1) and (2)

Comment: This answer is for fixed format - so call your file trap.f and you'll be fine.